# How to get User Email from third party access token asp.net web api2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, access-token

I am trying to modify the default method GetUserInfo() porvided along with Visual Studio  Web api template. My problem is that i can get user email when it is not registered in my application. But if user is registered externalLogin is null.

```
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("UserInfo")]
public UserInfoViewModel GetUserInfo()
{
 ExternalLoginData externalLogin = 
    ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
        string email = externalLogin.Email; 
    // i can get email if user is not registered.
        return new UserInfoViewModel
                    {
                        Email = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
                        HasRegistered = externalLogin == null,
                        LoginProvider = externalLogin != null ? 
                        externalLogin.LoginProvider : null
                    };
   }
```

I can get user name of that third party token by below code.

```
var username = User.Identity.Name;
```

But i need to get email of that accesstoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get email by adding claims inside method GenerateUserIdentityAsync().

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager, string authenticationType)
 {
  // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
 var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType);
 userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, UserName));
 userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Email));               
   // Add custom user claims here
   return userIdentity;
  }
```

Then inside GetUserInfo() Method i was able to pull the email using below code.

```
var userWithClaims = (ClaimsPrincipal)User;
var email = userWithClaims.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email).Value;
```